# Picasa opens Opera by default - why?

Tags: opera, picasa

When I request to open Picasa Web Albums from within desktop Picasa 3.6, the Opera browser is used even though it's not my default browser (FF is). How can I "fix" this?

Comment: Some more information about your environment would help people diagnose. OS? What other browsers are installed besides Firefox? Where are you showing that Firefox is your default browser?

Comment: Windows 7 x64, installed browsers are Firefox, IE9 and Opera. If I double-click a HTML file on my local PC it opens in FF as expected. From some applications like Picasa Web Albums Opera opens instead (I think I've seen this is some other app too but I can't remember which one it was). I can't explain it.

Answer (score 2):

> Go to Control Panel, search for Default Programs, choose Set your
>   default programs, Select Firefox, Click on Choose defaults for this
>   program, and check the boxes next to HTTP and HTTPS, Hit Save.

As a last resort (if that still does not work), you could use the same interface to set first Opera as the default browser for all files and protocols (related to browsers), instead of only HTTP and HTTPS, then set FireFox afterwards the same way as you did with Opera.